# How to validate form ViewModel with MVVM Data binding in Android?

Tags: android, validation, mvvm, data-binding, formvalidation.io

I am trying to validate a form with mixed data type inputs from user.
I also have Optional/Required field along with Regex validations.
I have implemented Android Data binding using MVVM and hence I can now not use [saripar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar).

I tried [Kubwa](https://github.com/WesleyElliott/Kubwa) but i can not use duplicate annotations there. 
I have also had a look at [android-binding](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146085/Model-Validation-Support-in-Android-Binding),but I couldn't implement the library and also they don't support it anymore.
Let me know if anyone can suggest better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if by "duplicate annotations" you mean multiple of the same type (2 or more `@Email` validations) - then Kubwa will work. All the annotations have a `.List` sub annotation for such situations:

```
@NotNull.List({
    @NotNull(name = "streetError", errorMessage = R.string.streetError),
    @NotNull(name = "cityError", errorMessage = R.string.cityError),
    @NotNull(name = "countryError", errorMessage = R.string.countryError)
})
```

Disclaimer - Kubwa is my library :)

Comment: i really like your library but have tried very hard to set it up to no avail.can you please help me

Comment: @Pamparanpa - what issues are you having?

Comment: @Boots have you tried that in Kotlin? It says "An annotation can't be used as the annotations argument"

Comment: Solved: Inner NotNull annotations must be without the @
`@NotNull.List(
        NotNull(name = "cardError", errorMessage = R.string.error_field_required),
        NotNull(name = "nameError", errorMessage = R.string.error_field_required),
        NotNull(name = "lastNameError", errorMessage = R.string.error_field_required)
)`

Comment: I am getting this error: Error:Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.wesleyelliott.kubwa.KubwaCompiler could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/wesleyelliott/kubwa/rule/Rule

Comment: @InsaneDeveloper, it might be better to ask a new question or open an issue on the project's Github